# Animate drawn image

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I've got some problem. I have an image drawn using canvas, and I would like to animate it. I would like to do something like `TranslateAnimation`, but `TranslateAnimation` works only with  views, and my image is not a view. What can I do?

Comment: I highly doubt you image is not a view as every thing you see on the screen is a View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I haven't worked with Android canvas, but I am fairly certain that what you need to do is this:

1. Draw your shape on the canvas
2. Wait for a couple of miliseconds
3. Clear the canvas
4. Redraw shape to next immediate position

and repeat this until the final position is reached.

From my little knowledge the canvas is more similar to a piece of paper than to a flash animation. You need to draw, clear, recalculate, redraw. I highly recommend reading some more on the topic. Firstly, I would start with the android canvas reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

and then try some tutorials like canvas frame by frame tutorial for android : http://developingthedream.blogspot.ro/2011/01/android-canvas-frame-by-frame-animation.html

And also I highly recommend looking up things on google first before posting a question on stack. There is a good chance, especially if you are a beginner, to find existing tutorials with everything you need and more. Good luck learning.